# Java GUI extremely slow

Tags: java, performance

I'm writing a Java app and the GUI is extremely slow on my Ubuntu 11.10 64bit setup. It takes a few seconds to respond to some action. 
It runs flawlessly on both Max OS X and Windows 7, it actually works just fine on a fresh Ubuntu 11.10(both 32 and 64bit) VirtualBox running on Win7.

I have already tried three different Java versions and it didn't help.
What could be the problem?

Current Java version:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Is it Sun/Oracle or OpenJDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try installing version 1.7 (oracle's one, not openjdk), and making sure it is the active version using update-alternatives and java -version.

Do note, however, that java is NOT a fast technology. Your applications are compiled to intermediate bytecode which needs to be interpreted by a fairly heavy application called the JVM. Although I don't remember ever having experienced multiple seconds of interface lag, I do know the GUI's written in java tend to be slow.

I've never noticed any difference between windows 7 and ubuntu/opensuse though (each 64-bit), but that might be due to the version: I always get the latest official java sdk (that is, from Oracle).

--

Although this might not be the answer you'd like to hear, if you don't explicitely need java (which you would if you were targetting mobile devices, I suppose) and/or if performance is important for your application, you might want to look for a native-compiled alternative. C++ with Qt would be an excellent alternative, if you're familiar with C++. It keeps your application cross-platform, without affecting the general performance.

Mono/C# comes with an option to precompile the bytecode, so you basicly have a native executable with the mono runtime included (heavy at startup, but faster than java at runtime).

Comment: I had this problem also, but installing Oracle Java did NOT fix the problem.  I think Solerma's answer about it being a driver issue could be a good lead for many others with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

By your description, I would be it's a video driver issue. Looks for performance related issues regarding your video card in ubuntu. Inside a VM, ubuntu uses a VM-specific driver that have nothing in common with the hardware